# Regex for multiple words between special characters

Tags: java, regex

I'm trying to get every group of words with at least one word between some special characters with a regular expression in Java. These are some sample strings to clarify it:

```
{ ? <> <> ; <> ? ; <> ? . ? <> ? . ? <> ? . ? <> ? }
{ <> <> ? . <> <> ? }
{ <> <> <> }
{ OPTIONAL { <> <> ? } FILTER ( ! bound(?) ) }
{ FILTER not exists ( ! bound(?) ) }
{ <> <> ? . ? <> ? }
{ ? <> <> ; a <> }
{ <> <> ?@en }
{ <> <> <> }
{ <> <> ? . <> <> ? FILTER ( ? > ? ) }
{ <> <> ? . ? <> ? FILTER regex(? ?) }
{ <> <> ? FILTER ( ! bound(?) ) }
{ ? <> ? ; <> ? . ? <> ? }
{ ? <> ? ; <> ? . ?2 <> ? ; <> ? }
{ ? <> <> ; <> ? . ? <> ? }
{ <> <> ? . <> <> ? FILTER ( ? = ? ) }
```

My matches shall look like this:

```
OPTIONAL
FILTER
bound
FILTER not exists
bound
...
```

This is the regex I've come up with so far:

```
[^\d\W\\a\@]+
```

You can test it here: https://regex101.com/r/cP3Uri/2

My problem is that my regex will find only full words and no groups of words (with a space in between). This means this substring `FILTER not exists` will get 3 matches (one for every word) but I want it to be just one match.

Can anyone help me finding the correct regex?

Comment: how about  [`\\b[a-zA-Z ][a-zA-Z ]+\\b`](https://regex101.com/r/cP3Uri/6)

Comment: @Pavneet_Singh post it i think it is correct :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
\w+(?:\s*\w+)*
```

for capturing all groups including the 'a' and 2 character

```
\w{2}(?:\s*\w+)*
```

for only capturing groups with more than one character

you can replace \w with [a-zA-Z] to exclude digits.

see https://regex101.com/r/cP3Uri/7

Comment: Wouldn't `\s+` be more appropriate? `\s` will never match zero times.

Comment: You're right, I think `\w{2,}(?:\s+\w+)*` would be more appropriate. This says: match any word with more than one character and all words after that separated by a space. `\w{2}(?:\s*\w+)*` says match the first two characters and then all characters after that even if they are separated by a space.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`[a-zA-Z]{2}[a-zA-Z ]*\\b`](https://regex101.com/r/4llP9w/3) to find minimum a two character word

- `[a-zA-Z]{2}` : match exactly 2 upper or lower case letter
- `[a-zA-Z ]*\\b` : match zero or more upper and lower case characters , word boundary

To find only words followed by only words with spaces use

[`[a-zA-Z]{2}(?:\\s*[a-zA-Z]{2,})*`](https://regex101.com/r/zXhXUX/3)

Answer (score 1):

You can use one of these, which respect your original pattern:

```
[^\d\W\\a\@]([^\d\W\\a\@]| )*\b
[^\d\W\\a\@]+( +[^\d\W\\a\@]+)*
```

See demo: [1](https://regex101.com/r/vlIkgG/3) and [2](https://regex101.com/r/vlIkgG/4)